# Count total, active and inactive data by MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

My code sample for get total total_stamp, i need with active and inactive. My stamp table have current_status row for active and inactive

```
SELECT r.*
     , COUNT(s.current_status) total_stamp
  FROM tbl_registers r
  LEFT 
  JOIN tbl_stamps s
    ON r.register_id = s.register_id
 WHERE r.ins_id = 1
 GROUP 
    BY r.register_id
 ORDER BY r.register_name_en ASC
     , s.stamp_name_en ASC
```

[image]

Current output like that, I need another more column line one is total_active another is total inactive with single query.

Comment: How does one check whether or not a record is active or inactive?  And you're looking for two additional columns, correct?

Comment: yes I am looking for two additional columns. In amount 5 i.e. 2 is active and 3 is inactive already have in second table with current_status column name

Comment: For future reference read this:  http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/271056/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT r.*, 
       COUNT(s.current_status), 
       SUM(current_status='something meaning active') active,
       SUM(current_status='something meaning inactive') inactive,
       ...
```

should do the trick. Why? because expressions like `current_status='something meaning inactive'` in MySQL have the value 0 meaning false, or 1 meaning true. So `SUM()` adds up the number of true items.

Comment: There's a lot of guesswork in my answer because your question is incomplete.

Answer (score 1):

I think the best way to achieve this would be to split your `LEFT JOIN` up into two separate `LEFT JOINS`. One to the table where active and another where inactive. This way you will be able to sum the three separately. Does that make sense? Something like this:

```
SELECT r.*, sActive.total + sInactive.total as total_stamp, sActive.total as active_stamp, sInactive.total as inactive_stamp
FROM tbl_registers as r
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT register_id, COUNT(*) as total
    FROM tbl_stamps
    WHERE s.current_status = 'active'
    GROUP BY register_id
) as sActive ON sActive.register_id = r.register_id
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT register_id, COUNT(*) as total
    FROM tbl_stamps
    WHERE s.current_status = 'inactive'
    GROUP BY register_id
) as sInactive ON sInactive.register_id = r.register_id
GROUP BY r.register_id
```

Comment: Do you still think that?